# Use list as dependencies on add_custom_command

Tags: c, cmake

I want to use list ie., `set(RESOURCES foo.txt bar.txt foo.bar bar.foo)` as dependencies instead of typing out manually on `add_custom_command` DEPENDS part.

The actual real-life use case is for `glib-compile-resources` utility tool where a user can let it generate all the dependencies from the xml file using `--generate-dependencies` parameter. In our case, the output is stored on a variable using CMake's `execute_process()`. That way I don't have to manually update CMake script every time a new resource is added or removed from the xml file.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.15)

project(dummy LANGUAGES C)

find_program(GLIB_COMPILE_RESOURCES NAMES glib-compile-resources REQUIRED)

set(GRESOURCE_C      dummy.gresource.c)
set(GRESOURCE_XML    dummy.gresource.xml)
set(GRESOURCE_XML_IN dummy.gresource.xml.in)
set(GRESOURCE_DEPENDENCIES)

set(OLD ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/${GRESOURCE_XML_IN})
set(NEW ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/${GRESOURCE_XML})

if(NOT EXISTS ${OLD} OR (${OLD} IS_NEWER_THAN ${NEW}))
    configure_file(${GRESOURCE_XML_IN} ${GRESOURCE_XML})

    execute_process(
        WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}
        COMMAND ${GLIB_COMPILE_RESOURCES} --generate-dependencies ${GRESOURCE_XML}
        OUTPUT_VARIABLE GRESOURCE_DEPENDENCIES
    )
endif()

add_custom_command(
    OUTPUT ${GRESOURCE_C}
    WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}
    COMMAND ${GLIB_COMPILE_RESOURCES}
    ARGS
        --generate-source
        --target=${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/${GRESOURCE_C}
        {NEW}
    VERBATIM
    MAIN_DEPENDENCY ${GRESOURCE_XML}
    DEPENDS ${GRESOURCE_DEPENDENCIES} # <-- Here lies the problem
)

add_custom_target(
    dummy-resource
    DEPENDS ${GRESOURCE_C}
)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} dummy.c)
add_dependencies(${PROJECT_NAME} dummy-resource)
```

## dummy.gresource.xml.in

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<gresources>
    <gresource>
        <!-- touch foo.glade && touch bar.glade -->
        <file>foo.glade</file>
        <file>bar.glade</file>
    </gresource>
</gresources>
```

The dummy can just be hello world for now.

List isn't expanded on the above DEPENDS part. But if I manually type in all the dependencies it works. Is there a way to achieve the behavior I want?

Comment: Your `GRESOURCE_DEPENDENCIES` variable is empty in some cases. Try printing it and debugging the case.

Comment: The `configure_file` invocation already provides dependency from `${GRESOURCE_XML_IN}` file. So you may run `execute_process` **unconditionally**.

Comment: @Tsyvarev `execute_process` runs only once during build generation. So it's wise to place both `configure_file` and `execute_process` inside a condition to fetch new output values for `GRESOURCE_DEPENDENCIES` when xml.in file changes. Maybe, bad design but it works so :(

Comment: As already [noted by arrowd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63664809/use-list-as-dependencies-on-add-custom-command?noredirect=1#comment112579971_63664809), the problem with your approach is that some runs you leave `GRESOURCE_DEPENDENCIES` variable **empty**. But every invocation of `cmake`, which parses `CMakeLists.txt`, should find this variable filled with actual values (otherwise you would get empty `DEPENDS`, as you already found). You may, however, make `GRESOURCE_DEPENDENCIES` variable CACHE'd, so CMake will store its value between invocations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The source of the cause is the output value `GRESOURCE_DEPENDENCIES` we got from `execute_process()`

Try printing out its actual length as a list. We'll get size 1!

But the string printed using `message(${GRESOURCE_DEPENDENCIES})` is so convincing:

```
foo.glade
bar.glade
```

But that output is wrong! We only get that kind of output if `foreach()` loop is used in conjunction with `message()`. Without loop, a list printed using only `message()`, the correct output comes out like this:

```
foo.gladebar.glade
```

The remedy to this is simple:

1. Use `string(REPLACE "\n" ";" ...)` to convert our string value to a list
2. Pop out the last item because it's just a single `\n` whitespace character
3. *Thanks to the comments above* Set `GRESOURCE_DEPENDENCIES` as a persistent variable

## Corrected script

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.15)

project(dummy LANGUAGES C)

find_program(GLIB_COMPILE_RESOURCES NAMES glib-compile-resources REQUIRED)

set(GRESOURCE_C      dummy.gresource.c)
set(GRESOURCE_XML    dummy.gresource.xml)
set(GRESOURCE_XML_IN dummy.gresource.xml.in)
set(GRESOURCE_DEPENDENCIES CACHE INTERNAL "GResource dependencies for dummy")

set(OLD ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/${GRESOURCE_XML_IN})
set(NEW ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/${GRESOURCE_XML})

if(NOT EXISTS ${NEW} OR (${OLD} IS_NEWER_THAN ${NEW}))
    configure_file(${GRESOURCE_XML_IN} ${GRESOURCE_XML})

    execute_process(
        WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}
        COMMAND ${GLIB_COMPILE_RESOURCES} --generate-dependencies ${GRESOURCE_XML}
        OUTPUT_VARIABLE GRESOURCE_DEPENDENCIES
    )

    # OUTPUT_VARIABLE is not a list but a single string value with newlines
    # Convert it to a list and pop out the last newline character
    string(REPLACE "\n" ";" GRESOURCE_DEPENDENCIES ${GRESOURCE_DEPENDENCIES})
    list(POP_BACK GRESOURCE_DEPENDENCIES)
endif()

add_custom_command(
    OUTPUT ${GRESOURCE_C}
    WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}
    COMMAND ${GLIB_COMPILE_RESOURCES}
    ARGS
        --generate-source
        --target=${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/${GRESOURCE_C}
        ${NEW}
    VERBATIM
    MAIN_DEPENDENCY ${GRESOURCE_XML}
    DEPENDS ${GRESOURCE_DEPENDENCIES}
)

add_custom_target(
    dummy-resource
    DEPENDS ${GRESOURCE_C}
)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} dummy.c)
add_dependencies(${PROJECT_NAME} dummy-resource)
```