# How to use glib-compile-resources with CMake

Tags: cmake, gtk

As any GTK project grows, GTK applications tend to be bundled with gresources to separate out code and UI design. This is very useful because UI/UX designers don't need to know code in order to... well design and ultimately contribute their skills and effort to the project.

Not only designers but programmers too benefit a lot! Because code becomes heavily "logic or problem solving" instead of maintaining both UI and logic code together in one single file.

However, to compile our GResource we need `glib-compile-resources` utility tool. The command usually goes like this:

```sh
glib-compile-resources --generate-source --target=<output-file> <input-file>
```

But how do I create a build script that compiles our gresource files and link it with our target project? I'm still a newbie learning CMake and I've gotten far enough to know what a target is, how to set a variable, how to link a target, and also how to pull in the required GTK packages for linking. But I don't have any clue how to proceed ahead with solving this :(

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A solution to this is using `add_custom_command()` to compile your gresources. But first here's a breakdown of what you need for your CMake script:

1. Pull in **glib-compile-resources** as executable program - `find_program()`
2. Define how to compile your gresource - `add_custom_command()`
3. Then define your custom target - `add_custom_target()`
4. Tell CMake that resource is a generated file - `set_source_files_properties()`
5. Finally, add your custom target to your project target as a dependency - `add_dependencies()`

Here's a sample CMake script:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.15)

project(dummy)

# Step 1:
find_program(GLIB_COMPILE_RESOURCES NAMES glib-compile-resources REQUIRED)

set(GRESOURCE_C   test.gresource.c)
set(GRESOURCE_XML test.gresource.xml)

# Step 2:
add_custom_command(
    OUTPUT ${GRESOURCE_C}
    WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}
    COMMAND ${GLIB_COMPILE_RESOURCES}
    ARGS
        --target=${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/${GRESOURCE_C}
        ${GRESOURCE_XML}
    VERBATIM
    MAIN_DEPENDENCY ${GRESOURCE_XML}
    DEPENDS
        for.glade
        bar.glade
)

# Step 3:
add_custom_target(
    dummy-resource
    DEPENDS ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/${GRESOURCE_C}
)

# Step 4:
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} dummy.c ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/${GRESOURCE_C})
set_source_files_properties(
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/${GRESOURCE_C}
    PROPERTIES GENERATED TRUE
)

# Step 5:
add_dependencies(${PROJECT_NAME} dummy-resource)
```

## Brief explanation

### add_custom_command()

- `OUTPUT` - This is your generated resource file
- `WORKING_DIRECTORY` - Where your XML and glade files are located
- `VERBATIM` - Makes sure our `COMMAND` receives `ARGS` unchanged
- `MAIN_DEPENDENCY` - for glib-compile-resources <input-file>
- `DEPENDS` - Your glade file(s). If any of the file changes then your target build is triggered :)

### add_custom_target()

- `dummy-resource` - That's your custom target name
- `DEPENDS` - The output your custom target needs in order to trigger your custom command

### set_source_files_properties()

When you first generate your build files using `cmake` command, your resource file isn't generated yet. So CMake will run into error because it doesn't know where your resource file is or where it's coming from. We need to tell CMake "Don't fail, our resource file is generated later"

## Use `--generate-dependencies` instead of hard-coding

Now you might notice we are duplicating our effort ie., when we add new glade files or remove existing ones (or any other resources such as icon, sounds, css files, etc) we have to edit both our XML and CMake script files. `glib-compile-resources` already provide dependency generation so we can use that in our CMake script and make it smart.

The trick is to change your .xml file to .xml.in as a configuration file. So when that configuration file changes, you call glib tool with --generate-dependencies, get new dependency output values, and send that to `add_custom_command(... DEPENDS)`. Now we have an intelligent CMake :)

If you want to approach this method then the below post would be really helpful:

[Use list as dependencies on add_custom_command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63664809/use-list-as-dependencies-on-add-custom-command)

Good luck :)

Comment: And let's say I have multiple resource files (`file1.gresource.xml`, `file2.gresource.xml`) - what do I do so that I don't have to repeat `add_custom_command` twice in my CMake file? Is that possible?

Comment: Should be possible. Haven't actually encountered the need for that so far. However, I think looping each gresource file and then working on `add_custom_command` inside the loop should do the trick but don't know how the ouptut target dependency has to be handled. Maybe you could try it on a sample test project, figure it out, and create a new StackOverflow post. Could help me and future readers ;)